# Low Voltage H-Bridge

Tags: circuit-design, h-bridge

I am designing an H-Bridge to control the direction a peltier cell that is connected to a variable-control current source. The current will be a maximum of 5A. The DIR1 and 2 are 3.3V from a micro.

The problem is that as the input voltage is decreased to < Vgs the P-type FETs will start to turn off.

I have access to +12V. I thought of using N-FETs on the top and driving with the 12V but then I have a similar problem when the input voltage is near 12V.

I was thinking of using a negative supply to drive the top FETs, would that work? Surely, there must be a simpler solution?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnPyR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, search for **charge pump MOSfet driver** (specific device recommendations are discouraged here).

Comment: Alternatively, since your direction will only change occasionally, use a DPDT relay. 5 amps is available in quite small packages, and you only need a single direction control line.

Comment: @glen_geek I don't think typical charge pump drivers will work here, but  if you have a class of device in mind and can provide an answer it would be interesting (and would get upvotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to drive the p-channel MOSFETs with a dual photovoltaic optoisolator/gate driver. They are a mite slow, but that may not be a problem for you (make sure you don't get shoot-through current by delaying the n-channel turn-on, but not turn-off appropriately).

They take the energy from the internal LED and actually generate an isolated output voltage. The turn on is slow because they have to supply the gate charge. A special internal circuit speeds the turn-off by shorting the output when the LED turns off.

This avoids both the necessity of generating a negative supply and the necessary level-shifting. It also will avoid the possible problem of exceeding the maximum Vgs if the supply is at +12 and you drive the gates with -12.

As well, since the output gate drive voltages are isolated you are free to use n-channel MOSFETs for all four.

Comment: Using an isolated gate driver looks like a good solution. Is there a reason to choose the LED version over the capacitive or magnetic variants?

Comment: @KylePennington11  As far as I know the photovoltaic type is the only kind that does not require another power supply. There may be some other kinds of gate drivers with internal transformer-isolated supplies.